# React-Native, ActionSheetIOS display instead of Picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to use the `ActionSheetIOS` on `iOS`, instead of the native picker wheel.

My app crashes out, how can I display my component?

Here is my `Picker` component:

```
// Picker.ios.js    
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { StyleSheet, ActionSheetIOS, View } from "react-native";

const PickerList = props => {
  const { label, options, selectedValue, name, onChange, identifier } = props;

  return ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
    {
      options: options,
      cancelButtonIndex: 1,
      destructiveButtonIndex: 2
    },
    optionIndex => {
     console.log('clicked')
    }
  );
};

export default PickerList;
```

I'm using conditional rendering to display my pickers, and a platform specific import:

```
         import Picker from "./common/Picker";

           {setYear
                    ? <Picker
                          selectedValue={setGroup}
                          label="Year group"
                          onChange={this.onGroupChange}
                          options={
                              categories.find(category => {
                                  return category.id == setYear;
                              }).options
                          }
                      />
                    : null}
```

Comment: A `stack trace` for the error would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

ActionSheetIOS only shows the options, you have to have some view component to replace the picker in the view. I used TouchableOpacity ja ActionSheetIOS to replace Picker on IOS like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSelectCategory.bind(this)}>
  <Text style={styles.textInputStyle}>
    {this.state.category}
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

onSelectCategory() {
  ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
  { options: FEEDBACK_CATEGORIES},
  (buttonIndex) => this.setState({ category: FEEDBACK_CATEGORIES[buttonIndex] }));
}
```

1. I use this.state.category to show my selection in TouchableOpacity
2. When user press the TouchableOpacity the ActionSheetIOS is shown
3. When user select option the callback function is called and I update the 
   selected index to the this.state.category

Comment: Can I pass an array of objects to the `ActionSheet`? So I can use a `value` instead of an `index`?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I think not because docs say: "The 'callback' function takes one parameter, the zero-based index of the selected item." [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html)

Comment: Yeah, I looked around it seems to force the developer to link back the string to former list order. quite strange as a design decision.